# Mousepad "Lock when hit"

Tags: drivers, touchpad, lock

All right, I don't know how to say this, but I will try my best!

When i used Windows 7, I could touch my mousepad and "emulate" a left-click, but when I do this in Ubuntu, the mousepad temporarily locks, so the mouse wouldn't move.

So now, I am looking to be able to do the same thing in Ubuntu, but I can't seem to find it :( I think what did was the Synaptics driver, so maybe its impossible, just wanted to try the luck with the largest Linux community ^^

EDIT: Okay, maybe I didn't explain it well enough :P I am looking for a function which makes the mouse stay still when I tap on the mousepad, because the way it is now, I have the mouse over the desired button, but when I tap the mousepad, the mouse moves slightly, which can be a problem :P

Answer (score 0):

If you open **Ubuntu Software Center** then search for and install **synaptiks** this will give you options to left click by clicking on a corner of your touchpad.

[image]

I hope this helps

**UPDATE**

The only way that may work that I can think of is to set the pointer speed as follows

[image]

This should make the movement very slow when the mouse is stationary, but accelerates to a sensible speed when it is moved.

Comment: Well, it was somewhat what i was looking for, only thing is the function i need isnt there :( I have edited the desc. to be more precise :)

Comment: I have added a possible solution to my answer.

Comment: Well, its not a perfect solution, but is better than before :) Thank you very much, SimplySimon! :)